I am trying to pull data from Oracle to Databricks. Below are the JDBC parameters which I am trying to set to speed up the execution:
I am trying to copy data from an Oracle EDW to Databricks Unity Catalog (Delta) to speed up our monthly reporting process. There are almost 40-50 tables/views which have close to 200-300 M records with some a couple ranging to a billion records. Therefore, I was trying to apply partition on date column as most of them are monthly snapshots and hence distributing it on Spark nodes based on date would really speed up the load process.
Oracle DATE type takes everything as a timestamp format and hence to make sure the DATE type for partition is correct, I referenced the below post which explains how to deal Oracle date format with Spark:
How to set jdbc/partitionColumn type to Date in spark 2.4.1
def edw_pull(sql):
  query = (spark.read
                  .format("jdbc")
                  .option("url", "jdbc:oracle:thin:@reporting.datawarehouse.db.insideaag.com:1522/edwprod")
                  .option("user",oracleDBusername)
                  .option('password',oracleDBpassword) 
                  .option("dbtable", sql)
                  .option("driver", "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver")
                  .option("fetchsize","500000")
                  .option("numPartitions",64)
                  .option("partitionColumn", "RUN_DATE")
                  .option("lowerBound", '2024-06-01')  
                  .option("upperBound", '2024-10-01')  
                  .option("oracle.jdbc.mapDateToTimestamp", "false")
                  .option("sessionInitStatement", "ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'YYYY-MM-DD'")                              
                  .load())                  
  return query

This starts the Spark jobs for a couple seconds and then errors out with the below error:
Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 8 in stage 944.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 8.3 in stage 944.0 (TID 3819) (10.127.154.19 executor 1): java.sql.SQLDataException: ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string
Tried again:
Using to_date for lower/upper bound to convert date string to 'YYYY-MM-DD' but no luck.
Query string
query = f"""(select * from table where run_date >= DATE)
I also tried using to_char(run-date,'yyyy-mm-dd') >= '2024-01-01' in the query string but getting the same error.
If anyone has encountered this before, showing the right path would be of great help as a lot of analysts/engineers are pulling data in my org without applying the necessary optimization and hence leaving out the Spark's potential unexplored.

try converting your parameter to a date - where run_date > to_date('2024-01-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd')

Already tried that and mentioned in the tried again part as well

What is the format of the date/Timestamp column that you have in oracle database? because if your Oracle table is having the date/timestamp format as DD-MM-YY or something else jdbc connector won't be able to consider it as date and give you the error you mentioned.
